# RestTemplate response is deserialized into a LinkedHashMap when using a generic type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, resttemplate

I have a web API producing a response like this:

```json
{
    "code":0,
    "message":"success",
    "result": {}
}
```

Where result is an object/array of objects that depends on the request that was sent.

```java
private <T> ResponseEntity<CommandResponse<T>> sendRequest(SomeRequestBody body, HttpHeaders headers) {
        HttpEntity<SomeRequestBody> entity = new HttpEntity<SomeRequestBody>(body, headers);
        String url = "http://localhost:8081";
        return restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<CommandResponse<T>>() {});
}
```

CommandResponse looks like this:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CommandResponse<T> {

    public CommandResponse(int code, String message, T result) {
        this.code = code;
        this.message = message;
        this.result = result;
    }

    private int code;
    private String message;
    @JsonProperty("parameters")
    private T result;
}
```

Type **T** can be anything from a single String to an array of objects. Take below class as an example:

```java
@Setter
@Getter
public class UserBalanceResponse implements Serializable {
    private Double balance;
    private Double balanceHistory;
    private Double credit;
    private Double creditHistory;
}
```

The problem that the obtained response body looks like this:

[image]

With an array of objects the response looks as follows:

[image]

I'd appreciate any advice on how I can it be deserialized without manually converting each type.

Adding message converters or jackson deserializer is an option however I couldn't make it work so far to keep the generics.

--EDIT
To clarify, currently, I'm receiving the response - CommandResponse, where result object of type (T) is a LinkedHashMap and I need the result to be converted to object of type for example UserBalanceResponse.

Comment: sorry, what is your expected output ? i did not get the question completely

Comment: @RyuzakiL I've added an edit to clarify, I hope it makes sense :)